# "Text selection index was clamped (-1->0) to remain in bounds" in my description field

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form with a few fields, but only one is filled typed by the user. The "description".

```dart
child: Textarea(
  label: "Descrição *",
  onChanged: (value) => controller.setDescricao(value),
),
```

`Textarea` is a separated widget making use of another custom widget `TextInput`, which is:

```dart
return TextFormField(
  controller: TextEditingController(),
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  ...
```

I'm using MobX, and I have a `computed` operation `canSubmit` that verifies if the fields are not null, or in the case of "description", if it's not empty:

```dart
@computed
bool get canSubmit =>
    cliente != null &&
    projeto != null &&
    dataInicio != null &&
    dataFim != null &&
    (descricao.isNotEmpty || descricao != '');
```

The problem in question is somehow happening because if this. If I fill up all the fields and I let "description" to be filled last, the first letter or number I type will not appear in the field, and it will validate `canSubmit`. I tested with a simple `print(description.isEmpty)`, and after typing the first letter it would print `false`, even if, as I said, nothing is shown in the field. Not only this, but if I try to erase the empty letter, this message is displayed:

> D/flutter (28047): Text selection index was clamped (-1->0) to remain in bounds. This may not be your fault, as some keyboards may select outside of bounds.
>
> D/flutter (28047): Text selection index was clamped (-1->0) to remain in bounds. This may not be your fault, as some keyboards may select outside of bounds.

Yes, twice.

Comment: Met the same problem

Answer (score 2):

In my case, on Android, code of moving the cursor at the end of the input when user input caused

> Text selection index was clamped (-1->0) to remain in bounds. This may
> not be your fault, as some keyboards may select outside of bounds.

and hard to input expected text into the `TextFormField`

```
TextFormField(
 controller: _controller
  ..text = _title
  ..selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: _controller.text.length),

)
```

After I changed code of moving the cursor to `initState` [follow example from flutter document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html), it work fine now.

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      final text = _controller.text.toLowerCase();
      _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(
        text: text,
        selection:
            TextSelection(baseOffset: text.length, extentOffset: text.length),
        composing: TextRange.empty,
      );
    });
  }
```

```
TextFormField(
 controller: _controller,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
In TextField Use Like This
var _nameController;
on init(){
_nameController=TextEditingController(text:'');
}

onChange:(String newName){
                     model.name=newName;
                     _nameController.text=newName;
                                
                   _nameController.selection=TextSelection.collapsed(offset:_nameController.text.length);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

after call setState

```
controller: TextEditingController(),
```

create a new TextEditingController will cause selection error.
you can fix it use:

```
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text: text);
if (text != null) {
    controller.selection=TextSelection.collapsed(offset:text.length);  
} else {
    controller.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset:0);  
}

return TextFormField(
  controller: controller,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  ...
```